# Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'System.Byte[]

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Im getting this error when i compile the project dont know what refers to..
im trying to conver an image to a byte array so i can save it to a database

```
i've updated the versions and nothing happens

Error Mono.Linker.MarkException: Error processing method: 'System.Byte[] HeavenTaste.NuevaOrden::converterDemo(Xamarin.Forms.Image)' in assembly: 'HeavenTaste.dll' ---> Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.Void System.Drawing.ImageConverter::.ctor()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.HandleUnresolvedMethod(MethodReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethod(MethodReference reference)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkInstruction(Instruction instruction)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.MarkMethodBody(MethodBody body)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessMethod(MethodDefinition method)
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessQueue()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.ProcessPrimaryQueue()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process()
   at Mono.Linker.Steps.MarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.MonoDroidMarkStep.Process(LinkContext context)
   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.ProcessStep(LinkContext context, IStep step)
   at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process(LinkContext context)
   at MonoDroid.Tuner.Linker.Process(LinkerOptions options, ILogger logger, LinkContext& context)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.Execute(DirectoryAssemblyResolver res)
   at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.LinkAssemblies.RunTask()
   at Microsoft.Android.Build.Tasks.AndroidTask.Execute() in /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/external/xamarin-android-tools/src/Microsoft.Android.Build.BaseTasks/AndroidTask.cs:line 17 HeavenTaste.Android C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Legacy.targets  648
```

Comment: How are you getting this image data in the first place?  You should use the original data source to save the data.  You can’t get it from the Image control

Comment: yes i think im getting it right from the control

Comment: What's the database you are using in your project?

Answer (score 0):

```
private async void btnGuardar(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("",converterDemo(Vistaprevia).ToString(),"OK");
        }

 public byte[] converterDemo(Xamarin.Forms.Image x)
        {
            ImageConverter _imageConverter = new ImageConverter();
            byte[] xByte = (byte[])_imageConverter.ConvertTo(x, typeof(byte[]));
            
            return xByte;
        }
```

Comment: This is not an Answer to your question.  Please [edit] your question to add details